# How do I properly use Threads to connect ping a url?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I am trying to ping a large amount of urls and retrieve information regarding the certificate of the url. As I read in this thoughtbot article here [Thoughtbot Threads](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/untangling-ruby-threads) and others, I've read that the best way to do this is by using Threads. When I implement threads however, I keep running into Timeout errors and other problems for urls that I can retrieve successfully on their own. I've been told in another related question that I asked earlier that I should not use Timeout with Threads. However, the examples I see wrap API/NET::HTTP/TCPSocket calls in the Timeout block and based opn what I've read, that entire API/NET::HTTP/TCP Socket call will be nested within the Thread. Here is my code:

```
class SslClient
  attr_reader :url, :port, :timeout

  def initialize(url, port = '443', timeout = 30)
    @url = url
    @port = port
    @timeout = timeout
  end

  def ping_for_certificate_info
    context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
    certificates = nil
    verify_result = nil
    Timeout.timeout(timeout) do
      tcp_client = TCPSocket.new(url, port)
      ssl_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new tcp_client, context
      ssl_client.hostname = url
      ssl_client.sync_close = true
      ssl_client.connect
      certificates = ssl_client.peer_cert_chain
      verify_result = ssl_client.verify_result
      tcp_client.close
    end
    {certificate: certificates.first, verify_result: verify_result }
  rescue => error
    puts url
    puts error.inspect
  end
end

  [VERY LARGE LIST OF URLS].map do |url|
      Thread.new do
        ssl_client = SslClient.new(url)
        cert_info = ssl_client.ping_for_certificate_info
        puts cert_info
      end
    end.map(&:value)
```

If you run this code in your terminal, you will see many Timeout errors and ERNNO:TIMEDOUT errors for sites like fandango.com, fandom.com, mcaffee.com, google.de etc that should return information. When I run these individually however I get the information I need. When I run them in the thread they tend to fail especially for domains that have a foreign domain name. What I'm asking is whether I am using Threads correctly. This snippet of code that I've pasted is part of a larger piece of code that interacts with ActiveRecord objects in rails depending on the results given. Am I using Timeout and Threads correctly? What do I need to do to make this work? Why would a ping work individually but not wrapped in a thread? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Creating many operating system threads at once will cause them all to fight over resources, resulting in the timeouts that you are experiencing.  I"m not really a Ruby guy, but each Thread is an operating system thread, and requires a certain amount of memory and cpu-time, and most of your threads will sit there, twiddling their thumbs, waiting for the ping to come back, yet still taking up memory and cpu. More successful web servers use asynchronous communications, and even lightweight threads, like Erlang. Also, I hear NODE.JS is pretty successful. Copy what they do.

Comment: Use a [thread pool](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby/blob/master/docs-source/thread_pools.md); don't just create a thousand concurrent threads. For something like connecting to a URL where there will be a lot of waiting you can oversubscribe the number of threads per CPU core, but not by a huge amount. You'll have to experiment.

Comment: I used to do something similar a very long time ago and I used https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#making-parallel-requests. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the comment guys. Hey @anothermh do you have a recommendation for experimenting with Pools? I've seen some s.o. questions like this one where 50 was the connection pool at the starting point and then 5 threads, etc. etc. What determines the pool size? What do I need/look for while experimenting?

Comment: You don't need a connection pool. You just need a thread pool. What determines the thread pool size? CPU core count and IO wait times. 1 CPU core = 1 thread (usually), but since connecting to a URL involves a LOT of waiting you can run multiple threads per CPU. How much waiting is there? If they're hosts on your local network not much. If they're on the Internet there's more, but again it depends. That's why you have to experiment; use https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html to find the sweet spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

- You'd not spawn thousands of threads, use a connection pool (e.g https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool) so you have maximum 20-30 concurrent requests going (this maximum number should be determined by testing at which point network performance drops and you get these timeouts).
- It's difficult to guarantee that your code is not broken when you use threads, that's why I suggest you use something where others figured it out for you, like https://github.com/httprb/http (with examples for thread safety and concurrent requests like https://github.com/httprb/http/wiki/Thread-Safety). There are other libs out there (Typhoeus, patron) but this one is pure Ruby so basic thread safety is easier to achieve.
- You should not use `Timeout` (see https://jvns.ca/blog/2015/11/27/why-rubys-timeout-is-dangerous-and-thread-dot-raise-is-terrifying and https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-ruby-dont-use-timeout-77d9d4e5a001). Use `IO.select` or something else.

Also, I suggest you learn about threading issues like deadlocks, starvations and all the gotchas. In your case you are doing a starvation of network resources because all the threads are fighting for bandwidth/network.

Comment: Thank you Silex for these articles, libraries, and info. This is helping me move toward the right direction.

Comment: I have a follow up if you don't mind. On your first bullet point, why did you come to the number of 20-30 threads in one pool? Is this all determined by the network? I'm just trying to gauge how will I know to increase the number of pools as opposed to threads.

Comment: Well the main ressource you are using here is the network. If it was CPU the suggested thread count would be much lower (1 thread per CPU). It'd be determined by common sense and benchmarking, in my experience 20-30 concurrent requests is easily manageable but if you have low bandwidth then maybe this number should be 5 or so. You could also not use threads at all and use something based on Curl::Multi like Typhoeus does.

Comment: Just a clarification: in this case the connection pool size *is* the number of threads, which also is the number of concurrent requests. It does not make sense to have more threads than concurrent requests. Also to determinate this number consider if the requests are small requests or large downloads (large -> less threads).

Comment: Maybe a mathematic approach for the number of threads could be `BANDWIDTH / TYPICAL_REQUEST_SIZE`. That is if your connection is able to download at 2 MB/s and your typical request is 100KB, a good number is 20. Just keep in mind that if you have high number of threads and low number of CPUs you'll waste CPU cycles doing context switching, now as each thread will be mostly "waiting on the network" this can be ok.