# Is this Ruby code using threads, thread pools, and concurrency correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, concurrency

I am what I now consider part 3 of completing a task of pinging a very large list of URLs (which number in the thousands) and retrieving a URL's x509 certificate associated with it. Part 1 is [here (How do I properly use threads to ping a URL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160027/how-do-i-properly-use-threads-to-connect-ping-a-url) and Part 2 is [here (Why won't my connection pool implement my thread code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60175650/why-wont-my-simple-connection-pool-execute-these-simple-put-statements).

Since I asked these two questions, I have now ended up with the following code:

```
###### This is the code that pings a url and grabs its x509 cert #####

class SslClient
  attr_reader :url, :port, :timeout

  def initialize(url, port = '443')
    @url = url
    @port = port
  end

  def ping_for_certificate_info
    context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
    tcp_client = TCPSocket.new(url, port)
    ssl_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new tcp_client, context
    ssl_client.hostname = url
    ssl_client.sync_close = true
    ssl_client.connect
    certificate = ssl_client.peer_cert
    verify_result = ssl_client.verify_result
    tcp_client.close
    {certificate: certificate, verify_result: verify_result }
  rescue => error
    {certificate: nil, verify_result: nil }
  end
end
```

The above code is paramount that I retrieve the `ssl_client.peer_cert`. Below I have the following code that is the snippet that makes multiple HTTP pings to URLs for their certs:

```
  pool = Concurrent::CachedThreadPool.new
  pool.post do
    [LARGE LIST OF URLS TO PING].each do |struct|
       ssl_client = SslClient.new(struct.domain.gsub("*.", "www."), struct.scan_port)
       cert_info = ssl_client.ping_for_certificate_info
       struct.x509_cert = cert_info[:certificate]
       struct.verify_result = cert_info[:verify_result]
     end
   end

   pool.shutdown
   pool.wait_for_termination

   #Do some rails code with the database depending on the results.
```

So far when I run this code, it is unbelievably slow. I thought that by creating a thread pool with threads, the code would go much faster. That doesn't seem the case and I'm not sure why. A lot of it was because I didn't know the nuances of threads, pools, starvation, locks, etc. However, after implementing the above code, I read some more to try to speed it up and once again I'm confused and could use some clarification as to how I can make the code faster.

For starters, in this excellent article [here (ruby-concurrency-parallelism)](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/ruby-concurrency-parallelism/) . We get the following definitions and concepts:

> Concurrency vs. Parallelism
>   These terms are used loosely, but they do have distinct meanings.
>
> **Concurrency**: The art of doing many tasks, one at a time. By switching
>   between them quickly, it may appear to the user as though they happen
>   simultaneously. **Parallelism**: Doing many tasks at literally the same
>   time. Instead of appearing simultaneous, they are simultaneous.
>   ***Concurrency is most often used for applications that are IO heavy. For
>   example, a web app may regularly interact with a database or make lots
>   of network requests.*** By using concurrency, we can keep our application
>   responsive, even while we wait for the database to respond to our
>   query.
>
> This is possible because the Ruby VM allows other threads to run while
>   one is waiting during IO. Even if a program has to make dozens of
>   requests, if we use concurrency, the requests will be made at
>   virtually the same time.
>
> Parallelism, on the other hand, is not currently supported by Ruby.

So from this piece of the article, I understand that what I want to do needs to be done concurrently because I am pinging URLs on the network and that **Parallelism is not currently supported by Ruby.**

Next is where things get confused for me. From my part 1 question on Stack Overflow, I learned the following in a comment given to me that I should do the following:

> Use a thread pool; don't just create a thousand concurrent threads. For something like 
>   connecting to a URL where there will be a lot of waiting you can
>   oversubscribe the number of threads per CPU core, but not by a huge
>   amount. You'll have to experiment.

Another user says this:

> You'd not spawn thousands of threads, use a connection pool 
>   (e.g https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool) so you have maximum
>   20-30 concurrent requests going (this maximum number should be
>   determined by testing at which point network performance drops and you
>   get these timeouts)

So for this part, I turned to `concurrent-ruby` and implemented both a `CachedThreadPool` and a `FixedThreadPool` with10 threads. I chose a `CachedThreadPool because it seemed to me that the number of threads needed would be taken care of for me by the Threadpool. Now in concurrent ruby's documentation for a pool, I see this:

```
pool = Concurrent::CachedThreadPool.new
pool.post do
  # some parallel work
end
```

I thought we just established in the first article that parallelism is not supported in Ruby, so what is the thread pool doing? Is it working concurrently or in parallel? What exactly is going on? Do I need a thread pool or not? Also at this point in time I thought connection pools and thread pools were the same just used interchangeably. What is the difference between the two pools and which one do I need?

In another excellent article [How to Perform Concurrent HTTP Requests in Ruby and Rails](https://pawelurbanek.com/ruby-concurrent-requests), this article introduces the `Concurrent::Promises` class form concurrent ruby to avoid locks and have thread safety with two api calls. Here is a snippet of code below with the following description:

```
def get_all_conversations
  groups_thread = Thread.new do
    get_groups_list
  end

  channels_thread = Thread.new do
    get_channels_list
  end

  [groups_thread, channels_thread].map(&:value).flatten
end
```

> Every request is executed it its own thread, which can run in parallel because it is a blocking I/O. But can you see a catch here?

In the above code, another mention of parallelism which we just said didn't exist in ruby. Below is the approach with `Concurrent::Promise`

```
def get_all_conversations
  groups_promise = Concurrent::Promise.execute do
    get_groups_list
  end

  channels_promise = Concurrent::Promise.execute do
    get_channels_list
  end

  [groups_promise, channels_promise].map(&:value!).flatten
end
```

So according to this article, these requests are being made 'in parallel'. Are we still talking about concurrency at this point?

Finally, in these two articles, they talk about using `Futures` for concurrent http requests. I won't go into the details but I'll paste the links here.

1.[Using Concurrent Ruby in a Ruby on Rails Application](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2018/06/05/using-concurrent-ruby-in-a-ruby-on-rails-application.html)
2. [Learn Concurrency by Implementing Futures in Ruby](https://www.sitepoint.com/learn-concurrency-by-implementing-futures-in-ruby/)

Again, what's talked about in the article looks to me like the `Concurrent::Promise` functionality. I just want to note that the examples show how to use the concepts for two different API calls that need to be combined together. This is not what I need. I just need to make thousands of API calls fast and log the results.

In conclusion, I just want to know what I need to do to make my code faster and thread safe to make it run concurrently. What exactly am I missing to make the code go faster because right now it is going so slow that I might as well not have used threads in the first place.

### Summary

I have to ping thousands of URLs using threads to speed up the process. The code is slow and I am confused if I am using threads, thread pools, and concurrency correctly.

Comment: If real parallel execution is needed use [jruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby#supported-ruby-versions). Since it is based on Java, each new thread is a real thread that can run in parallel. MRI will do context switching between threads but the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock) means only one executes at a time. You can see performance improvements even with MRI when using threads for things like connecting to URLs where a thread may be waiting x ms for a server response allowing a context switch but it'll never be as fast as jruby.

Comment: Also, unless you need to run this synchronously within your app I'd recommend [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) to run them asynchronously. Takes away a lot of the work you have to put into concurrency. And if you are able, you can have a job processor in [Elixir](https://github.com/akira/exq) which will give you MUCH better performance. Rewriting something this simple in Elixir shouldn't take too long. (but depending on your needs, the infra for it might make it not worthwhile)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us look at the problems you have described and try to solve these one at a time:

You have two pieces of code, `SslClient` and the script which uses this ssl client. From my understanding of the threadpool, the way you have used the threadpool needs to be changed a bit.

From:

```
pool = Concurrent::CachedThreadPool.new
pool.post do
 [LARGE LIST OF URLS TO PING].each do |struct|
    ssl_client = SslClient.new(struct.domain.gsub("*.", "www."), struct.scan_port)
    cert_info = ssl_client.ping_for_certificate_info
    struct.x509_cert = cert_info[:certificate]
    struct.verify_result = cert_info[:verify_result]
  end
end

pool.shutdown
pool.wait_for_termination
```

to:

```
pool = Concurrent::FixedThreadPool.new(10) 

[LARGE LIST OF URLS TO PING].each do | struct |
  pool.post do 
   ssl_client = SslClient.new(struct.domain.gsub("*.", "www."), struct.scan_port)
   cert_info = ssl_client.ping_for_certificate_info
   struct.x509_cert = cert_info[:certificate]
   struct.verify_result = cert_info[:verify_result]
  end
end

pool.shutdown
pool.wait_form
```

In the initial version, there is only one unit of work that is posted to the pool. In the second version, we are posting as many units of work to the pool as there are items in `LARGE LIST OF URLS TO PING`.

To add a bit more about Concurrency vs Parallelism in Ruby, it is true that Ruby doesn't support true parallelism due to GIL (Global Interpreter Lock), but this only applies when we are actually doing any amount of work on the CPU. In case of a network request, CPU bound work duration is very negligible compared to the IO bound work, which means that your usecase is a very good candidate for using threads.

Also by using a threadpool, we can minimize the overhead of thread creation incurred by the CPU. When we use a threadpool, like in the case of Concurrent::FixedThreadPool.new(10), we are literally restricting the number of threads that are available in the pool, for an unbound threadpool, new threads are created for everytime when a unit of work is present, but rest of thre threads in the pool are busy.

In the [first article](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2018/06/05/using-concurrent-ruby-in-a-ruby-on-rails-application.html), there was a need to collect the result returned by each individual workers and also to act meaningfully in case of an exception (I am the author). You should be able to use the class given in that blog without any change.

Lets try rewriting your code using Concurrent::Future since in your case too, we need the results.

```
thread_pool = Concurrent::FixedThreadPool.new(20)

executors = [LARGE LIST OF URLS TO PING].map do | struct |
  Concurrent::Future.execute({ executor: thread_pool }) do
    ssl_client = SslClient.new(struct.domain.gsub("*.", "www."), struct.scan_port)
    cert_info = ssl_client.ping_for_certificate_info
    struct.x509_cert = cert_info[:certificate]
    struct.verify_result = cert_info[:verify_result]
    struct
  end
end

executors.map(&:value)
```

I hope this helps. In case of questions, please ask in comments, I shall modify this write up to answer those.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it. I still have some reading to do regarding threads as a topic but from your answer it seems that I did need to use two things. 1) A thread pool and 2) A Future.

Comment: @DanRubio You really, really do not need futures.

Comment: @anothermh hey thanks for the comment and your input. For what reason do you say that I don't need the Future? The last two articles that I've linked argued for the usage of futures. To get a better understanding of the concept in general, can you tell me your reasons why you think I don't need them? Or maybe direct me to some articles/resources to read up on them?

Comment: Futures overly complicate what is a very straightforward problem you're trying to solve. See my comments on the question: just use an async job processor like Sidekiq, call the async worker once per URL, and let the processor handle the concurrency. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I agree with @anothermh, if you can get away with an async job processor like Sidekiq, I do suggest you use it. That would get you a lot more support from the community from Sidekiq community, and the chances of a bug are far less.